# Проблемы с градиентом CSS

Tags: html, css

Возможно это из-за невнимательности, но скорее из-за незнания. Пишу обычное меню, с событием li a:hover задний фон элемента списка меняется на градиент. Вот фрагмент кода:

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation" class="column span-5">
    <ul>
        <span>Навигация:</span>
        <li><a>Ссылка 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Ссылка 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Ссылка 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Ссылка 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text - decoration: none;
    text - align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover {
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,177,239) 24%, rgb(118,213,255) 62%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,177,239) 24%, rgb(118,213,255) 62%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,177,239) 24%, rgb(118,213,255) 62%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,177,239) 24%, rgb(118,213,255) 62%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,177,239) 24%, rgb(118,213,255) 62%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.24, rgb(84,177,239)),
    color-stop(0.62, rgb(118,213,255))
);
color:#fff;
}
```

Все отлично работает в Firefox и Opera, но Chrome отказывается показывать градиент. Почему?

Comment: А у [меня][1] всё нормально


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPzTq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже разобрался, Chrome не воспринимает простой тэг <a>. Добавил атрибут href и все заработало. Буду иметь ввиду.